# MIPS and interlocked stages

Tags: mips, pipeline

I'm studying the MIPS architecture, but i really don't understand some concepts..

For example, the "without interlocked pipelined stages".
I've also red that only first implementations of MIPS didn't have it (interlocked pipelined stages). But i didn't find with witch one it was introduced, can someone tell me in witch one it was introduced?

I want to focus on "interlocked stages". I've understand that this concept means, for example, adds explicit nop operations that delays the execution of an instruction (for example a branch). Is that true? or my conclusion is poor?

Morover, if the first version of MIPS didn't have the "interlocked stages", how did it manage the branch prediction?

Thank you all in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> adds explicit nop operations that delays the execution of an instruction

Rather than "adding a nop", the instruction in a delay slot is executed with the understanding that the architectural state is delayed — that the effect of the immediately prior instruction won't be see by the instruction in the delay slot.

It goes to having software do the "interlocking" instead of the hardware.

When the hardware doesn't interlock, delay slots are exposed to software and so software must accommodate, by shuffling code, or if it can't find anything useful to do in the delay stot, then filling that delay slot with a nop instruction.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot :

> > A load delay slot is an instruction which executes immediately after a load (of a register from memory) but does not see, and need not wait for, the result of the load. Load delay slots are very uncommon because load delays are highly unpredictable on modern hardware. A load may be satisfied from RAM or from a cache, and may be slowed by resource contention. Load delays were seen on very early RISC processor designs. The MIPS I ISA (implemented in the R2000 and R3000 microprocessors) suffers from this problem.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS_II :

> > MIPS II removed the load delay slot

Although not totally clear from those wikipedia articles, the branch delay slot apparently slowly disappeared, first in MIPS II, by providing versions of branches that only executed the delay slot instruction on taken branch, then in MIPS32, "a new family of branches with no delay slot".

In summary, delay slots have been abandoned, as they really only worked for specific micro architectures; since as the technology evolved, those designs features became challenges rather than offering their original benefit.

> Morover, if the first version of MIPS didn't have the "interlocked stages", how did it manage the branch prediction?

As I understand it, MIPS I didn't really do dynamic branch prediction but rather that it would simply assume not-taken branch, however, by delaying the execution of a branch for one instruction, it reduced the cost of assuming a not-taken branch when the branch was actually taken.  It also supported only very simple conditional branch instructions (e.g. equal or not equal), such that the branch taken/not-taken computation could be executed earlier in the pipeline, perhaps as early as in the ID stage.

Comment: I don't think it assumed taken or not, it just executed the branch, and the instruction immediately after regardless (because the branch took an extra cycle to take effect). If you were lucky, you could move the most likely instruction (e.g. the target if it was a loop) to that slot, and branch to the instruction after - if, that is, the instruction had no adverse effect (e.g. increment a register used only in the loop was fine, but if that first loop instruction damaged the state needed after exiting, you'd just put a nop and waste the cycle).

Comment: @JohnBayko, yes, that sounds right.